# What is a valid C# data-Type for the following return value or how can I access the inner properties?

Tags: c#, types

I have the following method:

```
private /*some type*/ abc(string a, string b){
    //...
    return new { success = false, responseText = "Input-Values not valid" };
}
```

Object is not the type I search for because than I can't access `abcReturn.success` and `abcReturn.responseText` in a second method. **Or is there another way to access the values of `success` and `responseText`?** Because when debugging, I can see that `abcReturn` really contains values for success and responseText.

I want to return it this way because in a third method, I want to do `return Json(abc(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: What about a named Tuple?

Comment: return new /*some type*/{} ?

Comment: or if you need it for json just use the json.net lib and create JObjects. for the json string call myobj.ToString() - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can't return a anonymous object in c# but you can return a named tuple like this:

```
private (bool success, string responseText) abc(string a, string b)
{
    return (false, "Input-values not valid");
}
```

Comment: I get: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes tuples because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TupleElementNamesAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: What version of c# are you using?

Comment: @JSteward Since the compiler know which type to look for, then it means it is high enough version of compiler.

Comment: @thestruggleisreal You may need a refrence to `System.ValueTuple` to use this syntax

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

private Dictionary<bool, string> abc(string a, string b) {
    //...

    Dictionary<bool, string> returnVal = new new Dictionary<bool, string>()
    {
        {"success", false},
        {"responseText", "Input-Values not valid"},
    };

    return returnVal;
}
```

And then to access the returned value, you would do: `returnVal["success"]`